# ajax query for button state for server

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, server

This is my button code ---

```
<a id="mylink" class="allow" href="#">
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
    {% trans %}Allow{% endtrans %}
  </button>
</a>
```

This is the way i find out to check the button status and store the button status in server whether it is **Allow or Not**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

  <AJAX CALL TO QUERY THE SERVER ABOUT THE BUTTON STATE>
  <RENDER BUTTON ACCORDING TO RESULTS>

  $('#mylink').on('click',function() {
   <AJAX CALL TO SERVER TO STORE STATE>
  });
});

</script>
```

Now my question is ----
1.  how i can do that query to server to check the button status

2. how i can write this method to store the state in server

can anyone solve this problem, with some coding example. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery, check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for ajax documentation.

client side code for getting state could look like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "getState.php",
  method: "POST"
}).success(function( state ) {
  // handle state
});
```

and code for setting state would be very similar

```
$.ajax({
  url: "setState.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { state : //state },
}).success(function() {
  console.log('state updated...');
});
```

But keep in mind that this is a very basic example. You should at least handle errors.

You're gonna also need to do some server side scripting to save state somewhere (maybe database) and to get it